# Regular expression not parsing URL properly Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that contains URLS that range in complexity. Here is a sample:

```
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
http://www.cs.jhu.edu/news-events/news-articles/
maps.google.com
http://www.cnn.com/WORLD/?hpt=sitenav
http://www.cnn.com/JUSTICE/?hpt=sitenav
http://www.cs.jhu.edu/course-info/
http://e-catalog.jhu.edu/departments-program-requirements-and-courses/engineering/computer-science/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html
http://mexico.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_Mexico
cnn.com
```

From these lines, I only want to get the "X.Y" part. In other words, from the first 4 lines, I want to get:

```
google.com
jhu.edu
google.com
cnn.com
```

In order to do this, I made a regular expression and I am attempting to match it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\homework4file.txt"));
        String line = null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.(com)$");
        Matcher matcher;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

My regular expression is just returning "com" for each line. I don't see what's wrong with what I've written. Could someone explain the logic error in my expression?

Comment: It's not O to 9 . It's zero to 9.

Comment: `group(1)` returns whatever is in the first capture group, i.e. the first thing you have in parentheses `()` in your regex.  The only thing you have in parentheses is `(com)`.  Therefore, `group(1)` returns `com`.

Comment: `maps.google.com` is a relative URL with one path component which is `maps.google.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put anchors. `^` asserts that we are at the start, but the part before `.com` isn't at the start. `[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+` would matches greedily the part before `.com` upto a `/` is reached. In this `http://mexico.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_Mexico` string, the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.(com)` would matches `mexico.cnn.com` not `cnn.com`.And also by putting `com`, `edu` into a non-capturing group delimited by `|` would also match the string before `.edu`.

```
[^.\\n]+\\.(?:com|edu)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/6)

```
String input = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl\n" +
"http://www.cs.jhu.edu/news-events/news-articles/\n" +
"maps.google.com\n" +
"http://www.cnn.com/WORLD/?hpt=sitenav\n" +
"http://www.cnn.com/JUSTICE/?hpt=sitenav\n" +
"http://www.cs.jhu.edu/course-info/\n" +
"http://e-catalog.jhu.edu/departments-program-requirements-and-courses/engineering/computer-science/\n" +
"http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html\n" +
"http://mexico.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_Mexico\n" +
"cnn.com";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^.\\n]+\\.(?:com|edu)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
   }
```

**Output:**

```
google.com
jhu.edu
google.com
cnn.com
cnn.com
jhu.edu
jhu.edu
oracle.com
cnn.com
cnn.com
```

Comment: Glad it worked out.. You could use this `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\w{2,3}(?=\/|$)` also http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/7